# onClick Webservices error

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I have a problem with `Button` and `EditText` in Android.Here is my code:

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isOnline()) {
                if(Subject.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                    Subject.setError( "Subject is required!" );
                    return;
                }
                if(Body.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                    Body.setError( "Body is required!" );
                    return;
                }
                final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(
                        getActivity(), "Send email", "Sending.....", true);
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            int result = emailService.sendEmail(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                                    Subject.getText().toString(),
                                    Body.getText().toString()
                                    );
                            switch(result){
                                case 1:
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email send successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                                case -1:
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request Error !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    break;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        progDailog.dismiss();
                    }
                }.start();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please check your network connection... !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

My problem is this one : If I enter in `Body` edittext a text like `stackoverflow` it's works perfectly and email service is called.But,if I enter text like `stack overflow` with space,`ProgressDialog` doesn't appear and email service isn't called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's really nothing in the code that would cause that.  Have you tried debugging to see the flow of the program?

Comment: There's not enough code to locate the issue. Your snippet, should work.

Comment: I think i got problem : that i have in email service `HttpPost request=new HttpPost(url+"?email="+email+"&subject="+subject+"&body="+body);`.I can't send body like `stack overflow`,i need a special character like `stack-overflow` or `stack_overflow`.A URL must not contain a literal space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your followup comment (code still not provided) you need to escape the URI before making your HTTP Post call - escaping the text will replace " " with %20 and allow spaces in the subject and body.

Comment: Thank you very much !. Now it's working perfectly.